# How to add RequiredFieldValidator on a Ajax Editor C#

Tags: c#, ajax, validation, editor

I am trying to add validation on Editor but it cants work. here is my code
when I run this and fill field its give me an error.

```
 <section style="padding-top: 120px" class="info-area pb-120 container-fluid">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-12 no-padding info-area-left">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="form-horizontal" runat="server" id="FormControls">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtUserName" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="inq" ErrorMessage="Enter name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" CssClass="form-control text-uppercase" runat="server" placeholder="Your name"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Testimonial</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Editor1" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="inq" ErrorMessage="Enter Testimonial"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" placeholder="Testimonial" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnSend" OnClick="btnSend_Click" CssClass="primary-btn text-uppercase" ValidationGroup="inq" runat="server" Text="Send" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

[image: Output Image] may helps you

Comment: Which error you've got? Can you provide markup (and code behind) inside `Editor` custom control/user control? Sounds like it's necessary to use `[ValidationProperty]` attribute.

Comment: when  I am finishing my Testimonial it shows me an error message like **Enter Testimonial** which I provide in `RequiredFieldValidator   ErrorMessage="Enter Testimonial" `